# Put button input center and another button right on the same line

Tags: html

I want to put the go-page button and input center and export button right on the same line, it doesn't work below

---

> `<div>
>       <P style="float: center">
>           <input type="text" id="page-dir" name="page-dir" maxlength="6" size="4" autocomplete="on"
>                  onkeydown="if (event.keyCode == 13)  document.getElementById('go-page').click()"/>
>           <button style="float: center" id="go-page" onClick="goPage()">go to page</button>
>       </P>
>       <P style="float: right">
>           <button id="export" onclick="export()">export</button>
>       </P>
>   </div>`

Comment: give some  code please

Answer (score 0):

```css
.container {
  display:block;
  text-align:center;
  width:500px;/*you can use percentage*/
  position:relative;
  border:1px solid #ff4500;
}
.cont-one {
   display:inline-block;
   max-width:150px;
  border:1px solid #000;
}
#page-dir{
  width:50px;
}
.cont-two{
  position:absolute;
  display:inline-block;
  width:50px;
  float:right;
  border:1px solid #000;
  left:450px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="cont-one">
    <input type="text" id="page-dir" />
    <button id="go-page" onClick="goPage()">Go to page</button>
  </div>
  <div class="cont-two">
    <button id="export" onclick="export()">export</button>
  </div>
</div>
```